# How to I use conditional formatting on a set number of cells instead of the whole row?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

This is my code that changes the entire row to red based off the word cancelled.  I only need the cells A:H in any given row to change not the entire row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
   
    If UsedRange.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If Trim(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)) <> "" And _
            UCase(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column)) = "CANCELLED" Then
            
            Rows(Target.Row).Interior.Color = vbRed
            Rows(Target.Row).Font.Color = vbWhite
            
        End If
    End If
ErrHandler:
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: change `Rows(Target.Row)` to `Range(Cells(Target.Row,1),Cells(Targe.row,8))`

Comment: Thank You.  I am very slow at recognizing what groupings mean what when it comes to code.  It worked as intended.